# C Reading numbers from text file into an array and using numbers for other function

Tags: c, arrays

I'm new so please excuse my lack of proper coding language.

I have a text file that reads:

```
80 83 82 81
94 95 87 86
86 90 78 95
```

How can I read the text file that puts those into an array and then in another function that multiplies the first 2 numbers (I plan on doing much more calculations).

Comment: Please only ask one question. Is the reading in the bigger problem or the storing in an array, or the making a function?

Comment: Show us your code. What have you tried, and where are you stuck at?

Comment: What is your level of programming knowledge? Did you try finding a HelloWorld, then some tutorials on generic C, then some tutorials on reading input? If you would show what you already have, this would be more plain to readers.

Comment: Well, first you need to learn the language you want to be programming in. That is usually done with a good book, or appropriate course material...

Comment: @KUMA Code walls don't belong in comments; that belongs in your question, well formatted, and include descriptions of what you intended it to do, what you see to see it actually doing and how it differs from your expectations, and finally a specific question about where you seemed to go off the rails. [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51587412/edit) and make sure your code is well represented there, providing the information I described.

Comment: @WhozCraig my apologies, i was having difficulties with the question reading my code and formatting it to be a separate block. However, my question was answered.

Comment: @KUMA Barr will be happy to hear that. Don't forget to *accept* that answer if indeed solves your problem.

Comment: stackoverflow is NOT a free coding service. We expect you to have written some code, tested it, and found that it has a problem that you were unable to debug.  Then you should come here for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to read the file and put the numbers in an array use `fscanf()`:

```
 FILE *myFile;
myFile = fopen("somenumbers.txt", "r");

//read file into array
int numberArray[16];
int i;

for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) //instead of 16, your numbers length
{
    fscanf(myFile, "%1d", &numberArray[i]);
}

myFunction(numberArray); //call the multiplication method
```

to pass the array and multiple the first two numbers:

```
int myFunction(int param[]) {
     return param[0] * param[1];
}
```

Comment: when you mean my numbers length (where you commented) do you mean how many numbers are within the text file?

Comment: @BarrJ I am just curious, what exactly does the %id do?

Comment: What do you exactly mean with >mixed with 1? :)

Comment: had to replace '%id' to '%1d', it happens sometimes when you type to fast :D

Comment: No problem, so %1d means that the %1 stands fill your current array at your index with the whole number until the `whitespace` and %d stands naturally for ineger am I right?:D

Comment: the OPs question states only 12 entries in the input file, so why is the code trying to read 16 entries?

Comment: %1d  is NOT correct.  it should be %d   The `1` is meaningless, except to claim that each entry read is only 1 character wide

Comment: the call to `myFunction()`, in `main()`, is failing to actually make use of the returned value.

Comment: The posted code is missing a prototype for the function: `myFunction()` and is missing the statement: `#include <stdio.h>`